# Find predicted end of converging series

Tags: python, math, data-analysis, calculus

Disclaimer: I am not looking for code, just something as simple as a flowchart or some basic structure my code should follow

I have a number series in a text file that goes like this:

```
0.34302782910527
0.37393913133041
0.39628340173437
0.41309602248196
0.42616553587597
0.43659829870113
...
0.51072412039755
0.51104691029067
0.51135763586774
```

**I need to find the number it converges on** but I have no idea as to how I should do this.
These points are magically constructed from a function that takes in values > 2.
For the sake of this question, assume that these points were magically generated and there is no way to reverse engineer the formula for these points.
**Every successive point takes a greater amount of computation so Id like to keep the number of points needed low.**

Questions:

**Is there something in Numpy or Pandas that could help** me out and in that case, should I start learning Numpy or Pandas?

While I was thinking about this **I considered the Taylor series and my ideas for my program are roughly based on that concept**. I think I should work out by/dx for each value where y is the value and x is the index of the value. Then work out d2y/dx2 , d3y/dx3 ....   **Eventually, when d^ny/dx^n becomes negligible I will get the computer to predict the point where dy/dx is negligible and find the value for the point.** This works whether the curve generated is a minimum curve or an inflection point.
Would this work?

If it did how would I implement it?
I am considering generating and appending on data onto multiple text files which correspond to dy/dx, d2y/dx2 etc. After this I can use my data to extrapolate and predict where dy/dx is negligible and so work out an approximation for the number the sequence converges on.

I thought a bit about the accuracy of my data and found this python function:[Convert float to integer ratio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.as_integer_ratio). I could probably modify my code to give the exact result via fractions. Would this be feasible?

Comment: You say that these numbers are generated from a certain function, so what are the inputs for these outputs? Can you generate more numbers, and do you assume that inputs are given in ascending/descending order?

Comment: Do you get these numbers iteratively? If so, you can just check the difference between the last and the next number and stop if it's under a certain value

Comment: @user8408080 each value is more precise than the next but a lot more difficult to compute

Answer (score 0):

You first need the function and determine what type of series it is, then you can find the convergence of the series using tests for convergence.

I don't remember exactly but it is possible to find the limit for 2 tests in the tests for convergence I think.